# Writing PowerShell CmdLets in Python Dynamically

Tags: .net, python, powershell, ironpython, powershell-cmdlet

I want to be able to write PowerShell CmdLets using IronPython, and furthermore I need one CmdLet to look at the environment and add CmdLets to the PowerShell based on the contents. For example, reading a directory, and adding a CmdLet Remove- for every filename it sees there.

Comment: Can you be more clear on what you want to add ? Can't you do it in C#.

Comment: I'm sure I *can* do it in C#. I don't want to, though. I want to do it in IronPython...

Comment: You shouldn't define cmdlets dynamically like that.  Especially for things like individual files.

Comment: Yes, yes I should. I'm obviously not going to actually write a separate Remove- command for a bunch of files -- that was just an example of the dynamicity I need.

Comment: When you already know how to do it in C#, it should be no problem to transform this into IronPython, as you have access to the same framework. Do I miss something here?

Comment: The problem here is that an IronPython class is not a CLR class or compatible with a CLR class. A CLR class is static and an IronPython class is dynamic and the DLR, as far as I know, doesn't for example provide IronPython classes to have .net CLR attributes, which you need for CMDLET development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know it can't be done!

The problem here is that an IronPython class is not a CLR class or compatible with a CLR class. A CLR class is static and an IronPython class is dynamic and the DLR, as far as I know, doesn't for example provide IronPython classes to have .net CLR attributes, which you need for CMDLET development.

Comment: actually the way to do it is buried inside the latest update: https://ironpython.svn.codeplex.com/svn/IronPython_Main/Languages/IronPython/Samples/ClrType/clrtype.py